# Does Ubuntu 10.04 support TRIM for SSD?

Tags: ubuntu, trim

I read [here](http://www.hardware-revolution.com/best-ssd-hdd-august-2011/) that:

> [T]o use TRIM, you need a OS that supports it, such as Windows 7, Mac
>   OS X and some variants of Linux being the only ones as far as I know.
>   You also need a SSD that supports TRIM obviously. Note that OCZ, Intel
>   and a few other SSD manufacturers offer a utility that mimics what
>   TRIM does, for OSes that don’t support TRIM.

My question is whether or not Ubuntu 10.04 LTS authentically supports TRIM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Linux kernel 2.6.33 or newer is required for TRIM support; Ubuntu 10.04 runs 2.6.32.

Comment: alright, so do I need Ubuntu 10.10 to support trim, or the kernel can be upgraded on 10.04?

Comment: @alfish If you're gonna go off of the LTS releases, you might as well get onto 11.04; support for 10.10 ends in about 8 months.  10.10 and 11.04 should work just fine for TRIM support; note that you'll need to use ext4 for a filesystem, and you'll need to add `discard` to your disk's mount options (during the setup wizard or manually in `/etc/fstab`).

Comment: Thanks Shane, but 11.04 is not LTS: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: @alfish Yup - what I'm saying is that if you're moving off LTS, you might as well get onto a version that's going to be supported for 14 months instead of 8.

Answer (score 3):

No - Ubuntu Lucid Lynx 10.04 does not support TRIM. Newer Ubuntu versions does support it, because it is included in the kernel as of 2.6.33. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14923/whats-the-story-with-trim-support) you could find something more to read.

If you want to use Ubuntu 10.04 you would have to upgrade your kernel to 2.6.33 or newer. [Here](http://sites.google.com/site/lightrush/random-1/howtoinstalllinuxkernel2635onubuntu1004lucidfromubuntu1010mavericktheeasyway) is a good example. After you enable TRIM you would like to [test it](http://sites.google.com/site/lightrush/random-1/checkiftrimonext4isenabledandworking).